# return multiple values java for removing last part of a word

Tags: java, string

In my code, fromright method checks the length of `last[]` and returns only one string. I want to return all matched values. What's the solution?

```
public static String last[]={"es","e","s"};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    text tx=new text();
    String checkString = "lives";
    String fin=tx.fromright(checkString);
    System.out.println("remaining:  "+fin);
}

public String fromright(String wrd) {
    String tmp="";
    for (int i = 0; i < last.length; i++) {
        tmp=wrd.substring(0, wrd.length()-last.length);
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: Show us an example output you expect.

Comment: maybe that can work...but how?@Bubletan

Comment: What is this code supposed to do, exactly?

Comment: such as input:lives output:liv,live@ Brunaldo

Comment: @Mohammad `String[] array = new String[last.length];` and so on.

Answer (score 3):

You are overriding your tmp variable in your for loop every time. So you can only get one result. 
Use this instead or smth. similiar which can hold multiple values.

```
  public List<String> fromright(String wrd) {
            List<String> tmp= new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < last.length; i++) {
                tmp.add(wrd.substring(0, wrd.length()-last.length));
            }
            return tmp;
```

EDIT:
This does not work anymore.

```
String fin=tx.fromright(checkString);
    ^
```

Replace it with

```
List<String> fin= new ArrayList<String>(tx.fromright(checkString));
```

And print out all values with this

```
for(String s : fin) System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: @Mohammad What did you do?

Comment: replaced my method with your method@Murat K.

Comment: every line with List<String> shows error:"The type list is not generic,it cannot be parameterized by arguements<String>"@Murat K.

Comment: @MCMSE You need to import `java.util.List` and make sure there is no other class named `List` in your project (because such name is inappropriate and can cause problems).

Answer (score 2):

```
public List<String> fromright(String wrd) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < last.length; i++) {
        if(wrd.endsWith(last[i]))
           result.add(last[i]);
    }
    return result;
```